# Problem with printf when printing a variable having single/double quotes and special char

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have this script

```
COMMAND1="connect ;  -v \"FROM ( MON_GET_LATCH(CLOB('<latch_status>W</latch_status>'), -2 ) )\"  > Status"
COMMAND2="connect ;  -v \"FROM ( MON_GET_LATCH(CLOB( ), -2 ) )\"  > Status"

echo "$COMMAND1"
echo "$COMMAND2"

sudo -i -u db2inst1 bash << EOF
        sleep 10 &
        printf 'COPY eval : %s : %s\n'  '$COMMAND1' " \$( jobs -p )"
        printf 'COPY eval : %s : %s\n'  '$COMMAND2' " \$( jobs -p )"
EOF
```

When running

```
./xx
connect ;  -v "FROM ( MON_GET_LATCH(CLOB('<latch_status>W</latch_status>'), -2 ) )"  > Status
connect ;  -v "FROM ( MON_GET_LATCH(CLOB( ), -2 ) )"  > Status
bash: line 2: latch_status: No such file or directory
COPY eval : connect ;  -v "FROM ( MON_GET_LATCH(CLOB( ), -2 ) )"  > Status :  23245
```

We can see COMMAND1 errors out as it has single quotes. How to avoid this issue? I cannot change or make changes to the variable contents.

I expect no error in printf.

Answer (score 1):

> How to avoid this issue?

Properly *serialize* and *deserialize* variables and code.

```
COMMAND1="connect ;  -v \"FROM ( MON_GET_LATCH(CLOB('<latch_status>W</latch_status>'), -2 ) )\"  > Status"
COMMAND2="connect ;  -v \"FROM ( MON_GET_LATCH(CLOB( ), -2 ) )\"  > Status"
func() {
    echo "$COMMAND1"
    echo "$COMMAND2"
}

sudo -u db2inst1 bash << EOF
$(declare -p COMMAND1 COMMAND2)  # pass variables
$(declare -f func)  # pass code
func  # call it
EOF
```

Comment: Getting Error ./yy[8]: declare: not found [No such file or directory]
./yy[8]: declare: not found [No such file or directory]
bash: line 3: func: command not found

Comment: @BharatGoyal is `#!/bin/bash` the first line in your file? Good luck.

Comment: @BharatGoyal That error message suggests the script is running in dash instead of bash.

Comment: `declare: not found` You are not running bash. Run bash instead.

Comment: I thought "we" discouraged keeping commands in variables? This seems to ***take it to a whole 'nother level!*** (-;! Good luck to all.

Comment: @KamilCuk   #!/bin/bash worked. Can you explain this code as well?

Comment: Which parts are unclear to you?

Comment: $(declare -p COMMAND1 COMMAND2)  # pass variables
$(declare -f func)  # pass code

Comment: Do you understand `$(...)` commmand substitution? Did you try `declare` in your terminal and see the output? `declare` here is used to output variables and the function in a form that can be then sourced in another script.